# How to apply grouped/collapsed results on aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine

I've got a problem with the Field Collapsing feature of Elasticsearch. This collapsing feature does not seem to have any impact on my top_level aggregations, which messes up the user experience.

Example:

I only show the user 2 articles, but in reality these are just collapsed results and there are more than 2 articles available. Let's say it's 4 for one group and 5 for the other. So all aggregations operate on 9 articles instead of the 2 that I want.

Is there a way to apply my aggregations to grouped/collapsed hits similar to how the aggregations are automatically applied to the query.

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but I can describe the object in detail. On the top level I've got a query, aggregations, collapse, sort, _source. Inside the query I just filter by a specific color nested inside a constant_score. I don't have any nested aggregations. And inside the collapse I specify a field and inner_hits object with a size of 1 and a sort by price.

Comment: Here is a quote from Solr Documentation on what I'm looking for in Elasticsearch.

Comment: The CollapsingQParser is really a post filter that provides more performant field collapsing than Solr’s standard approach when the number of distinct groups in the result set is high. This parser collapses the result set to a single document per group before it forwards the result set to the rest of the search components. So all downstream components (faceting, highlighting, etc…​) will work with the collapsed result set.                 
       https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html

Comment: As per the documentation: `The collapsing is applied to the top hits only and does not affect aggregations.`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what makes me freak out a bit. How am I supposed to do it otherwise? It seems so straightforward and Solr has this feature, so I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: I think the thing that makes it so hard to understand is to make a mental leap from facets to aggregations. Because facets are by default top-level and cannot be nested, so all facets are applied to the top hist.